# What is the appropriate method to analyze this data which contains repeated measures and mutually exclusive factors?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I'm working with a data set that has 29 subjects.  Each subject was measured under four difference conditions.  Let's call them A,B,C, and D.  Within each condition a subject can belong to one of two mutually exclusive classifications, let's call them X and Y.  I would like to know what differences exist between X and Y within each category and across the different categories.  I'm less interested in differences among the categories as a whole.

When I run a t-test for X and Y within each category I find some significant results; however, this doesn't give me any data across categories.  Running a 2-way ANOVA makes all the comparisons I need but doesn't produce significant results.  Repeated measures ANOVA works fine for comparing the groups as a whole but when I try to use it to analyze both categories and classifications it fails because of the mutual exclusivity of the classification (which produces missing values).

I'd like to find the best way to analyze this data without sacrificing statistical power.  The best I can come up with right now is performing a series of t-tests and just correcting for multiple comparisons.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I agree that you are going to have to adjust for multiple testing because of all the testing and analysis that you have done already..  The consequence of multiple testing  is higher p-values which means loss of power.